# How do I display records containing specific information in SQl

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I select all records that contain "LCS" within the title column in sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.TITLE LIKE '%LCS%';
```

% is the wild card matcher.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the LIKE clause

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for all the tables with a column name which contains the LCS in them? If yes the do this

```
select table_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where column_name like '%lcs%'
```